# Log data for Symfony Profiler

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

I created a Bundle that calls an third party api.

Now i want to show the received data in the Symfony Profiler.

I created a CustomDataCollector (http://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler/data_collector.html). That all works fine. But how can i get or "save" the received response for the api?

I created a service that calls the api with curl like that:

```
$raw_response = curl_exec($ch);

    $response = json_decode($raw_response);

    if (property_exists($response, 'error') && $response->errors) {
        return ['status'=>false, 'msg'=> (string)$response->errors[0]->description ] ;
    } else {
        return ['status'=>true, 'msg' =>'Send Successfully' ];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd advise you to use the `logger` service for simple use-cases that don't require a specific collector. You can provide additional context to the logging:

```
/** LoggerInterface */
$container->get('logger')->error('There was an error on the API call.', array(
    'description' => $response->errors[0]->description
);
```

The `logger` data is saved to a profile by default. For more advanced use cases you might be looking for the processors: http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/processors.html